# How can we implement bulk upsert in sqlx for postgres?

Tags: postgresql, go, upsert, bulk, sqlx

So I have been trying to a bulk upsert.
Postgres supports it out of the box .
Sample Query

```sql
INSERT INTO table(col1, col2, col3, eligible ,created_at, updated_at)
                    VALUES (:col1, :col2, :col3 :eligible ,now(), now()) 
                    ON CONFLICT (col1, col2)
                    DO UPDATE SET col2 = excluded.col2,eligible = excluded.eligible, updated_at = now() RETURNING *
```

What I want to be able to do is use the jmoiron/sqlx library to create a bulk upsert using Named feature.

As mentioned here [Github issue](https://github.com/jmoiron/sqlx/pull/667#issuecomment-787731678) I am unable to do so.

Answer (score 3):

I wanted to answer this question myself as being a dev my first instinct was to look at stack overflow and get this out to the folks

Bulk upsert in sqlx was introduced recently in 1.3.0 I believe. It is detailed out in the README but being an ORM that it is a bunch of PRs have forwarded and reverted the changes to support multiple SQL flavors.

The current regex which identifies if a query is a bulk query expects the query to end in a space or a bracket , basically a placeholder.

Please see the commit [here](https://github.com/jmoiron/sqlx/commit/a1d5e64734233358bc4e0a54beddc18509071a95#diff-f99653da52c8c48a281ba4b1cb16ab2b0017a8e26dfe2a1a2efd0aa5ec7b92f0R227).

To solve this I was able to use inner functions and some bypass to make a bulk upsert provided by postgres work.

[Here](https://github.com/jmoiron/sqlx/pull/667#issuecomment-798352600) is the code for the same . Repasting here for convenience :

```golang
    sliceOfStructs := []model.Gamer{
        {
        UserID:   "123",
        Name: "aarengee",
        Address: "xd",
        Eligible: true,
        },
        {
            UserID:   "1234",
            Name: "aarengeeAgain",
            Address: "xd",
            Eligible: false,
        },
    }
    upsertQuery := "INSERT INTO gamer_details (user_id, name, address, eligible,updated_at) VALUES (:user_id,:name,:address,:eligible,now())"
    onConflictStatement := " ON CONFLICT (user_id, name) DO UPDATE SET address = excluded.address,eligible = excluded.eligible, updated_at = now() RETURNING *"
    query, queryArgs, _ := db.BindNamed(upsertQuery, sliceOfStructs)
    query = db.Rebind(query)
    query = query + onConflictStatement
    rows, err := db.Queryx(query, queryArgs...)
```

Answer (score 0):

I kept still getting the error when doing a batch insert with ON CONFLICT, so I found a solution that worked for me with a help of a friend. This was very hard to find but you can see more info here. https://www.prisma.io/dataguide/postgresql/inserting-and-modifying-data/insert-on-conflict#using-the-do-update-action

`...DO UPDATE SET (var1, var2, var3, var4) = (excluded.var1, excluded.var2, excluded.var3, excluded.var4)`

then you should be able to do this

`_, err := db.NamedExecContext(ctx, query, sliceObj)`

of course, you don't need to use the context if you don't want